# How to show a especific icon in ion list Ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a list and I would like to click in item and show icon checked only in item clicked

[image]

In ts I have the following code

```
selectDevice(device: any, i: any) {
    this.devices[i]; 
    this.show= !this.show; 
}
```

and in my view I have

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let device of devices; let i = index" (click)="selectDevice(device, i)" >
  <img src="assets/images/wi-fi.png" alt="" class="wifi-img">
  <ion-label>{{ device.SSID }}</ion-label>

  <img src="assets/images/checked.png" *ngIf="show|| device[i]" alt="" class="checked-img">
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this way

```
selectDevice(device: any, count: any) { 
     this.mostrar = !this.mostrar;
     this.SSID = this.devices.filter(e => e['SSID'] == device['SSID'])[0]['SSID']
}
```

and my view

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let device of devices; let i = index" (click)="selectDevice(device, i)" >
  <img src="assets/images/wi-fi.png" alt="" class="wifi-img">
  <ion-label>{{ device.SSID }}</ion-label>

  <img src="assets/images/checked.png" *ngIf="mostrar && device['SSID'] == SSID" alt="" class="checked-img">
</ion-item>
```